# R: Remove/do not read empty .csv files

Tags: r, corpus

I'm reading a list of csv files from a directory which some of the csv are empty and stored it in a Corpus. Is there a way to remove empty files from the Corpus or do not read empty csv files as it is causing problem when i use the function 'removeSparseTerms' later.

```
directory.location<-paste("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\testFiles",sep="")  
correspondenceCorpus<-Corpus(DirSource(directory.location,encoding="UTF-8"),readerControl=list(blank.lines.skip=TRUE,language="en_US"))

#clean data
correspondenceCorpus<-tm_map(correspondenceCorpus,content_transformer(tolower))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
my_text<-readLines("path/your/file.txt")
text<-text[nchar(my_text)!=0]
```